# Redbox Alternative?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, lightbox

I am building an app and want to have a lot of the site forms come up in a box over the screen with the background darkened out. I have seen redbox on github and it seems to do what I need it to do but I see that it hasnt been updated since 2007. Is there a new way to go about this? Any alternatives to redbox?

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at overlay effect in [jQuery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html)  - a pretty nice library with a lots of demos. This is a collection of modern user-interface components such as tabs, tooltips, overlay, scrollable and so on. Single JavaScript file weighs only 5.72 Kb.

There is another pretty nice box plugin: [jquery fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). It can display images, video, flash, html-content. Packed js weighs 15Kb. Very cool stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it, I am not super comfy with javascript but I am learning, I like the idea of redbox because it has ruby helpers built in already for me. Also, can I use jquery and prototype on my site or is it one or the other?

Comment: Usually it's one or the other.  The jRails plugin will provide functionality for most all of the prototype things you're missing by using jQuery though.

Comment: You can use it if you want but why for? jQuery with jRails replaces prototype. As a plus of jQuery users can download this library from google cdn, what decrease your traffic and should speed up page load. I suggest you to look at compass-jquery-plugin, which already has integrated jRails.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help, I just got done with the screencasts over at peepcode and am only comfortable with prototype at the moment, I will work on learning how to use jquery.

Answer (score 2):

we used facebox for popup the implementation and how to use popup on ajax subpages also explained http://www.spritle.com/blogs/?p=564. The ui for facebox is already given.Redbox development is stopped I think. I suggest to go for some other solution like thickbox, lightbox or any other solution if you want to apply your own style for your popup.But, in my opinion facebox is better.